# How to run python script from cmd as local system (elevated privilege)?

Tags: python, windows, cmd

I can run python script from cmd.exe (I added Python to windows environment. However, when I run cmd.exe as local system via PsExec, and try to run the script in the same way as before (script.py) - it says Can't find default Python. What do I do? Are the commands different when running as administrator?

Comment: I'm guessing you added python to your users ``PATH`` and not the system.

Comment: yes. how should I add it to system? well, I added it to environment variables

Comment: The environment variable editor lists the system variables in the bottom half of the dialog.

Comment: Ok, I checked, I did add Python to system variable path and created new python path with python packages - but still getting message Can't find default Python

Comment: Just to be clear, which OS? Windows, Linux, etc.? It sounds like Windows if you are running psexec.exe.

Comment: windows 7 ... I posted solution few hours ago as well... don't know why it is not published. Namely it was enough simply to run >python script.py instead of only >script.py as it is done usually.

Comment: It wasn't clearly stated in your question that you're trying to run exactly `script.py`. Please try to provide an explicit, minimal example in questions, which in this case would be a complete example command line. I could have saved you some time. PsExec doesn't `ShellExecute` files using registered file associations. To do that you could use `psexec -s cmd /c "path\to\script.py"` instead of hard-coding it as python.exe.